# Android Market categories

Tags: google-play

I have a problem with the Android Market.

Yesterday i publish in the android market my application in shopping category but untill today when i go in shopping category it's not here. Why ?

Comment: Is your application still on Android Market?  If so, which category is it found under?

Comment: My application is still in the android market and is under SHOPPING categories

Comment: Whats the problem with your app ? are you want your app to be in android Market or not ? or what else ? please clearify your question.

Comment: Don't worry I have fix. I was worry because i don't see the application in shopping category yet. But now there is. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general reminder, it can take several hours for your app to reach the store once it has been published.

Once your app has been published, Google can pull it if it violates the various terms & conditions to which you agreed when you published it. (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981?hl=en)

When in doubt, contact the Android support staff directly - they are pretty good about responding within the next business day.